# How to package Java GUI apps for Homebrew

Tags: java, homebrew, packaging

I'm trying to package a GUI app for homebrew, but I'm running into a problem.

I'm packaging with this installation script, as per the [instructions at the Frankel.ch blog](https://blog.frankel.ch/distributing-desktop-webapps/2/):

```
def install
    libexec.install Dir['*']
    bin.write_jar_script libexec/'FOSStriangulator.jar', 'fosstriangulator'
end
```

And I'm using `depends_on "openjdk"` as my dependency, as `depends_on :java => '1.8+'` recommended by the article doesn't work.

But when running this package, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/QuitHandler
```

Is this because, rather than a library, my app is a GUI app?

In the terminal, running just via `java -jar` works fine for me.

Comment: Other questions mentioning that class indicate that it's no longer supported since Java 9. That `QuitHandler` is/was Mac OS X internal API that's no longer accessible in recent versions. Specifically processing applications seem to have a problem with this.

Comment: com.apple.eawt.QuitHandler has been replaced with [Desktop.setQuitHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#setQuitHandler(java.awt.desktop.QuitHandler)) as of Java 9.

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, `QuitHandler` was removed, but if you absolutely must use JDK 8, you can try copying one of the homebrew/core formulae that requires it. For example, the [`digdag`](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/digdag.rb) formula:

```rb
class Digdag < Formula
  url "https://dl.digdag.io/digdag-0.10.3.jar"
  sha256 "200911b6a35a3d8b40e25f028753fb9652aeb19dbd05b8f950dc35ff69547c34"

  depends_on arch: :x86_64 # openjdk@8 is not supported on ARM
  depends_on "openjdk@8"

  def install
    libexec.install "digdag-#{version}.jar"
    bin.write_jar_script libexec/"digdag-#{version}.jar", "digdag", java_version: "1.8"
  end
end
```

In your case, you probably want something like this:

```rb
class Fosstriangulator < Formula
  url "..."
  sha256 "..."

  depends_on arch: :x86_64 # openjdk@8 is not supported on ARM
  depends_on "openjdk@8"

  def install
    libexec.install Dir["*"]
    bin.write_jar_script libexec/"FOSStriangulator.jar", "fosstriangulator", java_version: "1.8"
  end
end
```

- `depends_on :java => '1.8+'` is replaced by `depends_on "openjdk@8"`
- The parameter `java_version: "1.8"` should be added to `bin.write_jar_script`